# how to write .d.ts file for js file which export a pure object?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying add .d.ts file for existing js file.

`type.js` file like this:

```
// type.js
export default {
    NORMAL: '001',
    CHECK: '002',
};
```

And add `type.d.ts` file like this:

```
// type.d.ts
declare namespace col_type {
    const NORMAL: string;
    const CHECK: string;
}
```

But in my project, after import `type.js`, VSCode show error like this:

```
import TYPE from './type';
```

error:

> File './type.d.ts' is not a module.

I honestly can't figure out what I should do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration file is missing the export:

```
declare namespace col_type {
    const NORMAL: string;
    const CHECK: string;
}
export = col_type;
```

Comment: Thank you, I add `export default col_type`, and it works!

Comment: And I found that, in the declaration file, the format of export must be the same as js file. 

In js file, the format is `export default {}`, then in declaration file, alse `export default xxx`. And if js file use `export { xxx }`, declaration file must be `export { YYY }` as well.