# What's the easiest way to import local JS modules into TS files?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a project that has a TS compiler that is set to strict and it gives an error that the JS I'm import has no type and was implicitly set to "any".

I don't know how to fix it without converting the entire file to Typescript.

One of the files im trying to import is in a different folder, something like `../lib/HttpServer`. I tried creating a HttpServer.d.ts file with `declare module HttpServer` in it, but nothing changed.

Comment: Where is the module from? Have you checked the `@types`? (e.g. `npm install @types/http-server` if the module is called `http-server`)

Comment: Also, if you use imports your declaration file should define exports, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53811426/546730).

Comment: This is a local file I'm importing, so there won't be a public type repo.

I'll double check that I exported the module when i get home. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That SO link was perfect! Thanks HB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to H.B.'s comment he linked to an answer that resolved my issue:
[how to write .d.ts file for js file which export a pure object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53811426/546730)

Essentially you need to make a .ds.t file with the definitions you need exported. You only need to export the ones you're using in your TS files.

This is essential for making the gradual transition from JS to TS.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
const xxx = require('your_module');
```

Comment: Instead of `import HttpServer from '../lib/HttpServer';`?